# pandas changing category of raw data

Tags: python, pandas

How I can convert following raw data into something easier for computation

```
    info.teams

    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['India', 'West Indies']
    ['India', 'West Indies']
    ['Bangladesh', 'West Indies']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Bangladesh', 'India']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['India', 'West Indies']
    ['India', 'South Africa']
    ['Afghanistan', 'India']
    ['India', 'South Africa']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['India', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['India', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['India', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Bangladesh', 'West Indies']
    ['Afghanistan', 'India']
    ['India', 'South Africa']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
    ['Bangladesh', 'West Indies']
    ['India', 'West Indies']
    ['Bangladesh', 'West Indies']
    ['Bangladesh', 'India']
    ['India', 'South Africa']
```

This is the datatype of the column.

```
info.teams                 1547 non-null object
```

Suppose if i want to find out the teams that have played together for eg. `['India','Australia']` I Have to code as follows:

```
#choosing particular teams 
team_1='India' 
team_2='Australia' 
team_12='['+"'"+team_1+"'"+', '+"'"+team_2+"'"+']' 
team_21='['+"'"+team_2+"'"+', '+"'"+team_1+"'"+']' 
df=df[(df['info.teams']==team_12) | (df['info.teams']==team_21)]
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. Mention what kind of computation

Comment: since 'info.teams'  is non-null object, its difficult for me to compute me every time, by computation i mean , suppose if i want to find out the teams that have played together for eg. ['India','Australia'] I Have to code as follows:


#choosing particular teams
team_1='India'
team_2='Australia'
team_12='['+"'"+team_1+"'"+', '+"'"+team_2+"'"+']'
team_21='['+"'"+team_2+"'"+', '+"'"+team_1+"'"+']'
df=df[(df['info.teams']==team_12) | (df['info.teams']==team_21)]

Comment: Not able to format above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is in the form of string then use `ast.literal_eval` to conver them to list, apply `pd.Series` and then use isin to select the columns i.e

```
import ast 
df['teams'] = df['teams'].str.strip().apply(ast.literal_eval)

ndf = df['teams'].apply(pd.Series)
ndf[ndf.isin(['India','Sri Lanka']).all(1)]

        0          1
14  India  Sri Lanka
15  India  Sri Lanka
16  India  Sri Lanka
```

If you want to select the data from the main dataframe then use the index from ndf i.e

```
idx = ndf[ndf.isin(['India','Sri Lanka']).all(1)].index

df.loc[idx]

            teams
14  [India, Sri Lanka]
15  [India, Sri Lanka]
16  [India, Sri Lanka]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you looking for. But if you want to get the teams in two separate columns , then you may want to do something like this :

```
   info[['team1','team2']]=pd.DataFrame(info.teams.values.tolist())
```

out put:

```
    teams     team1 team2
  0 [aus,ind]   aus    ind
```

Comment: No, Look at the question.. Suppose if I want to check If the trees that i want are present there or not, I have to do stupid write above always , is there any better get away than writing above code ? the code written in the questions..
How can i change the datatype from non-null object to something better which will help in comparisions